# rotate an image untill i stop it, but finish rotation in html/css/jQuery

Tags: html, jquery-animate, image-rotation

How do i make an image rotate until a stop function is called, but once it is called it should finish the rotation so that it always end at a certain point.
I'm using html5, javascript and jQuery.

btw. it is supposed to run on iOS, android and Blackberry, if it makes any changes??

Basically i got this css:

```
.spinning{
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s infinite ease;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0%   {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg)} 
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg)}
}
```

so right now, to animate i simply add the class "spinning" to what i need to spin, and remove the class when is should stop.
but this instantly rotates it back to 0 degrees once i remove the class.
what i want is this animation, but when i stop it, it should finish it's current rotation.

edit:

I have tried using jQuery, but can't figure out what to put instead of "rotation: 360"

```
function startAnimation(){
    $('#refreshButtonImage').animate(
        {rotation: 360},
        1000,
        function(){
        startAnimation();
    });
};
```

Comment: What does your animation code look like?

Comment: You'll have to detect current rotation angle and complete the rotation with jQuery. You're probably better off doing all the animation with jQuery for simplicity. Take a crack at it and update your question with that code. It'll probably get reopened.

Comment: Problem is, i did try using jQuery, i'm guessing i can put some kind of rotation, and when it's done check if it should rotate again, and so forth, but i can't figure how to put the css rotation in as a property.

Comment: Correct--you'd do a repeating animation, checking the status of a variable each time. On click, you'd set the variable to indicate that the animation should not continue.

Comment: but how? i edited my Question with what i tried, but it doesn't work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/sp2k6/

Comment: is it posible to do without the step function, it's not very smooth. i got alot of java running in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay. so i got a solution that i'm very happy about, since it does not require javaScript to run the actual animation.

css:

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0%   {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg)}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg)}
}
```

javaScript:

```
var keepSpinning = false;
function spin() {
    $('#Image').animate({
            borderSpacing: -360
        }, {
            start: function () {
                $('#Image').css({
                    '-webkit-animation': 'spin 2s 1 ease'
                });
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('#Image').css({
                    '-webkit-animation': ''
                });
                if (keepSpinning){
                    spin();
                }
            },
            duration: 2000
        });
}
function startSpin(){
    keepSpinning = true;
    spin();
}
function stopSpinning(){
    keepSpinning = false;
}
```

Thanks for the help finding the solution.